# Не изменяется переменная цикла

Tags: python

У меня есть тип данных list. Например, `list_example=[1,2,3,4]`
Я хочу удалить всё его содержимое, используя цикл for

Код, который я написал:

```
list_example=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0,len(list_example)):
    del list_example[i]
    i-=1
```

Но проблема в том, что переменная 'i' похоже не может быть изменена в данном цикле...

Comment: Learn about code indenting in Python ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменения переменной `i` внутри цикла не имеют никакого смысла, так как на следующей итерации в качестве `i` будет взят очередной элемент, полученный из `range`.

Поэтому не важно, уменьшаете ли вы в конце каждой итерации `i` на единицу, обнуляете ли вы её, или вообще уменьшаете на миллион. Всё равно в начале итерации `i` будет принимать очередное значение из ряда `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы понимаете, что, удаляя значение из списка, вы его уменьшаете? Поэтому, при заданном в цикле for параметре range у вас всегда будет вылетать ошибка с индексом.
Если уж вы хотите использовать функцию del, то попробуйте идти по списку не с начала в конец, а наоборот:

```
list_example=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(list_example)-1, -1, -1):
    del list_example[i]
    print(i)

print(list_example)
```

Получим:

```
3
2
1
0
[]
```

Comment: Но вопрос-то совсем не об этом. Автор не может понять, почему он в конце каждой итерации уменьшает i на единицу, но это ни на что не влияет.